# System.Threading.ThreadStateException (maybe a raise condition)

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, thread-safety

First, I would like to describe the general structure of the classes/methods involved in my problem.
I have a class which should start a thread cyclically. This thread deals with a function which writes the log entries into a log file. I realized this with a timer (`System.Threading.Timer`). Further there is a ThreadHandler class which keeps all threads in a list. These threads are controlled with the standard functions of `System.Threading.Thread` by the name of the thread. Now to the code that is affected by my problem:

In the constructor of my Log class (`LogWriter`) I call the method `InitializeLoggerThread()`:

```
private void InitializeLoggerThread()
{
    LoggerLoggingThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(WriteLog));
    LoggerLoggingThread.Name = LoggerLogginThreadName;
    ObjectObserver.ThreadHandler.AddThread(LoggerLoggingThread); // Obersver class from which all objects can be accessed
}
```

The Timer itself will be starte das

```
public void StartLogging()
{
    this.LoggerTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(LoggerCallback, null, 1000, LoggerInterval);
}
```

Furthermore the Log class contains the implementation oft he timer:

```
private const int LoggerInterval = 5000;
private System.Threading.Thread LoggerLoggingThread;
private static void LoggerCallback(object state)
{
    if ((BufferCount > 0))
    {
        ObjectObserver.ThreadHandler.StartThread(LoggerLogginThreadName);   
    }
}
```

The `ThreadHandler` will strart the thread with te following function:

```
public void StartThread(string threadName)
{
    lock (Locker)
    {
        if (GetThread(threadName).ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped || GetThread(threadName).ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
        {
            GetThread(threadName).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I have already checked the parameters etc.. Everything is correct in this case. Basically, when debugging, it seems that the threads all try to start the logger thread at the same time.

The thread will be calles by its name with the following function:

```
public Thread GetThread(string threadName)
{
    foreach (Thread thread in Threads)
    {
        if (thread.Name == threadName)
        {
            return thread;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now to my question: What is the error in my construct that I get

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException at StartThread(...)

after the first execution a multiple attempt of the execution?

If desired, I can provide a copy&paste code of all important functions for debugging.

Comment: When you attempt to start a thread with `ObjectObserver.ThreadHandler.StartThread`, could it already be running? (despite your state variable indicating that it isn't)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I don't think so. It seems more like several work threads are running over `lock(Locker)` at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread passes through a set of states ([taken from here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26675/Beginner-s-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-2-of-n)):

[image: Thread state machine]

Once thread is completed you cannot start it again. Your timer function tries to start `Stopped` thread though:

```
if (GetThread(threadName).ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped ...
    GetThread(threadName).Start();
```

There are awesome logging frameworks in .NET, such as [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) and [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), please don't try to reinvent the wheel, most likely these frameworks already can do what you need and they are doing that much more efficiently.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, but I'm a little surprised. For me the approach that you can't restart a stopped thread is a bit strange. I would have assumed that this is best practice, because otherwise, my current point of view is: 1. threadend => dispose => reinitialize (new Thread())
2. Stop the thread after completion of the operation and continue with new data if available.
Is that really the case? Unfortunately, I couldn't read an explicit statement in the provided link (I might have overlooked it). That would mean I have a basic design problem and therefore my mistakes.

Comment: State machine is described on the diagram: once thread is in `Stopped` state it cannot move anywhere else. Creation of a thread is rather expensive operation, you may use a thread pool instead, for example once you have some data - go and start a [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl). [Multithreading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-basics) is a tough topic, you need to be very explicit on what you are doing otherwise there is a big chance that you'll shoot your leg.

Comment: For example, if `LoggerCallback` takes more time than `LoggerInterval`, `System.Threading.Timer` will pick the thread and invoke `LoggerCallback` again. depends on what you have inside of that callback you might get lock convoys or thread pool starvation. Any unhandled exception inside of `WriteLog` will crash the entire application. If you have buffer and you need to read from it asynchronously, I'd use 1 thread with infinite loop reading from [BlockigCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)